# How to create a Sorting And Order Argument Class for use by many Class?

Tags: java

I have a class for do sorting and ordering from a list of object.

This is my class.

```
public class SortingAndOrderArguments {
    public SortingAndOrderArguments() {

    }

    @Nullable
    @PositiveOrZero
    private Integer offset;

    @Nullable
    @Positive
    private Integer max;

    @Nullable
    @Pattern(regexp = "id|corpName|address1|address2|joinDate|dateCreated|status")// <- ??
    private String sort;

    @Nullable
    @Pattern(regexp = "asc|ASC|desc|DESC")
    private String order;


    public Optional<Integer> getOffset() {
        if(offset == null) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        return Optional.of(offset);
    }

    public void setOffset(@Nullable Integer offset) {
        this.offset = offset;
    }

    public Optional<Integer> getMax() {
        if(max == null) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        return Optional.of(max);
    }

    public void setMax(@Nullable Integer max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    public Optional<String> getSort() {
        if(sort == null) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        return Optional.of(sort);
    }

    public void setSort(@Nullable String sort) {
        this.sort = sort;
    }

    public Optional<String> getOrder() {
        if(order == null) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        return Optional.of(order);
    }

    public void setOrder(@Nullable String order) {
        this.order = order;
    }
}
```

At this line:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "id|corpName|address1|address2|joinDate|dateCreated|status")
```

I just can sort this column `id|corpName|address1|address2|joinDate|dateCreated|status`.

How if i have other Class or Object that I have to sort with different column's name?

I think i must not create multiple SortingAndArgument. 
For example: `StudentSortingAndOrderArguments`, `SchoolsSortingAndOrderArguments`, etc.

Comment: Your question is too abstract to really be answerable in this state other than pointing you at an explanation of [how to sort stuff in java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-comparator-comparable). If you want better answers, please add a [mcve] with some example data being sorted in some way.